# Unable to pass wildcard character to stored procedure using asp:ControlParameter

Tags: sql, asp.net, sqldatasource

I have an aspx page that allows a user to enter in a string `asp:ControlParameter` that is then passed to a stored procedure using the `SelectCommand`.

The problem is if a user enters `123456%` in the text box to get all matches, a datareader error is thrown by the calling console.aspx page.  If they enter `123456` it works fine.

The stored procedure use to include the code:

```
l.nbr = @Nbr + '%'
```

This would return all possibilities, however the users wanted it to only return the exact match unless they entered the wildcard `%` in the text box.

I have written a query in SSMS to duplicate what I want and it works fine.

What is causing the data reader to not be able to pass my parameter with wildcard character to a stored procedure?

ASPX Code:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsBook" runat="server"
    SelectCommand="spLoadList" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"
    CancelSelectOnNullParameter="False">
 <SelectParameter>
     <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtNbr" 
                           Name="Number"            
                           Type="String" DefalultValue="" 
                           PropertyName="Text" />
 </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

stored Procedure:

```
    SELECT
        b.Id
    FROM dbo.Book b 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.BookStatus ls
        ON b.Id = bs.Id
    WHERE (b.Id IN (SELECT BookId FROM dbo.BookActiveView WHERE UserId = @UserId AND ApplCd = 'BT' ) )
    AND ( b.Nbr LIKE @Nbr )  <-- This is where it used to say ( b.Nbr = @Nbr + '%' )
    ;
```

Comment: post your code (asp and sql). Is it a numeric parameter?

Comment: `l.nbr = @Nbr + '%'` only returns if there are records that match `123456%`... `l.nbr LIKE @Nbr + '%'` is the code that would return all matching records that start with `123456`

Comment: My apologies, but the code I had entered is (b.Nbr LIKE @Nbr) replacing the original (b.Nbr = @Nbr + '%') I missed typed it above. 

asp:ControlParameter doesn't properly pass '%' in a string to the stored procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your stored procedure:

```
SELECT
    b.Id
FROM dbo.Book b 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.BookStatus ls
    ON b.Id = bs.Id
WHERE (b.Id IN (SELECT BookId FROM dbo.BookActiveView WHERE UserId = @UserId AND ApplCd = 'BT' ) )
AND ( b.Nbr LIKE @Nbr )  <-- This is where it used to say ( b.Nbr = @Nbr + '%' )
```

Note  `( b.Nbr LIKE @Nbr )` This will behave as you wanted as @balexandre  commented.

If user type only '12345' it will bring exact match. If they type '12345%' it will bring all starting with 12345

Also other [wildcards](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp) apply